# Redirecting all non-subdomain requests to (https)apex domain with Nginx

Tags: regex, linux, web, nginx

I have a fairly complex Ruby application that gives customers a dashboard available under their own chosen subdomain. i.e.: `http://mycompany.app.com`, `http://myproject.app.com`.

I also have the product website running on the root domain (i.e., `http://app.com`) and I've bought and configured an SSL certificate with Nginx and it's working as expected, but that leaves me  with the following problem scenario:

I need to redirect all non-https traffic to the https version of the page, except for any requests going to any of the subdomains. What makes it tricky is that I do however need to redirect the www version of the site to the non-www version.

```
http://app.com             -> https://app.com
http://www.app.com         -> https://app.com
http://nike-admin.app.com !-> https://nike-admin.app.com
```

Here's what I have come up with so far in nginx.conf for this app (real name replaced by `app`):

```
upstream unicorn_server {
  server unix:/var/www/<app>/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name <app>.co;

  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
  }
}

server {
  server_name <app>.co;
  root /var/www/<app>.co/public;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<app>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<app>.key;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
  }
}
```

In the first server{} block, I explicitly listen for any connection on port 80 and redirect those to the https version, but that's a double-edged sword as the SSL certificate only covers the apex domain. I don't want requests on any subdomains other than www to be redirected to the https equivalent.

I could potentially use regex, but from what I've seen online, but it seems to be frowned upon?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: *"I could potentially use regex, but from what I've seen online, but it seems to be frowned upon?"* -- What do you mean? I wouldn't frown upon using RegEx for this. Where'd you see that?

Comment: Regular expression engines are finite state, and most of the time you'll find writing a few lines of regex easier to maintain than several blocks of code anyway. For dedicated services you'll be using a lot, it's true that performance matters, but for this case, use regex.

Comment: any particular reason to have non-HTTPS for applications? do you want cookies to be stolen?

Comment: @mikhailov the dashboards on the subdomains are disposable read only with non-sensitive data, so the cost of a wildcard SSL cert doesn't make sense in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below regex:

```
/^.*?\b(?!www\.)((?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+).*$/
```

Replace with:

```
https://$1
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aF1cY0/8)!

- `^` Asserts position at the  start of string.
- `.*?` Matches any number of characters except new line in lazy match. (Char by char)
- `\b` Asserts a word boundary position (`\w\W` or `\W\w`.)
- `(?!` Negative lookahead: Asserts that our position is **NOT**:
- - `www\.` The character sequence **"www."**.
- `)` Then carry on the match:
- `(` Opens a *capturing group*. This is so we can use a back-reference in the replacement.
- - `(?:` Opens a non-capturing group.
- - - `[\w-]+\.` Any sequence of word characters or hyphens (because hyphens may be in domain names) followed by a dot.
- - `)+` One or more groups.
- `[\w-]+` Another group of word characters or hyphens.
- `)` Closes the group.
- `.*` Matches the rest of the string but it's not part of the domain, hence ignored.
- `$` Asserts position at end of string. This anchor may not be necessary, but it's good to have for readability.

---

Read more:

- [How to get domain from a string using javascript regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323169/3622940)

Answer (score 2):

```
(http:\/\/(www\.)?)([a-zA-Z-]+\.)(?![a-zA-Z-]+\.)
```

This will match:

1. Anything that uses `http`; or
2. Anything that starts with `www`.

This will **NOT** match:

1. Anything that has a subdomain.

If you wanted to do a ruby replacement, here are some examples (in irb):

http://app.com (switches to https)

```
2.1.1 :047 > "http:\/\/app.com".sub /(http:\/\/(www\.)?)([a-zA-Z-]+\.)(?![a-zA-Z-]+\.)/, 'https://\3'
 => "https://app.com"
```

http://www.app.com (switches to https)

```
2.1.1 :046 > "http:\/\/www.app.com".sub /(http:\/\/(www\.)?)([a-zA-Z-]+\.)(?![a-zA-Z-]+\.)/, 'https://\3'
 => "https://app.com"
```

http://subdomain.app.com (stays the same)

```
2.1.1 :045 > "http:\/\/subdomain.app.com".sub /(http:\/\/(www\.)?)([a-zA-Z-]+\.)(?![a-zA-Z-]+\.)/, 'https://\3'
 => "http://subdomain.app.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this construction and it works fine:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.site.ru www.my.site.ru;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://my.site.ru$1 permanent;
}
```

I also have _http://(www.)site.ru http(s)://(www.)othermy.site.ru domains and it's ok.

Starting from version 0.8.4 it should be better to use

```
        return          301             https://$http_host$request_uri;
```