# How to get domain from a string using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching, capturing-group

As the title suggests, I'm trying to retrieve the domain from a string using javascript regular expression.

Take the following strings:

```
String                                  ==>     Return
"google"                                ==>     null
"google.com"                            ==>     "google.com"
"www.google.com"                        ==>     "www.google.com"
"ftp://ftp.google.com"                  ==>     "ftp.google.com"
"http://www.google.com"                 ==>     "www.google.com"
"http://www.google.com/"                ==>     "www.google.com"
"https://www.google.com/"               ==>     "www.google.com"
"https://www.google.com.sg/"            ==>     "www.google.com.sg"
"https://www.google.com.sg/search/"     ==>     "www.google.com.sg"
"*://www.google.com.sg/search/"         ==>     "www.google.com.sg"
```

I've already read    ["Regex to find domain name without www - Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427603/regex-to-find-domain-name-without-www) and ["Extract root domain name from string - Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string)    but they were too complicated so I tried writing my own regular expression:

```
var re = new RegExp("[\\w]+[\\.\\w]+");
/[\w]+[\.\w]+/
re.exec(document.URL);
```

which works fine with `"google.com"`, `"www.google.com"` and `"www.google.com.sg"` but returns `http` with `"http://google.com/"`, `"http://www.google.com/"` etc.

As I am new  to regular expressions, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aF1cY0/5)!

Sampling:

```
>>> var regex = /(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/
>>> regex.exec("google.com")
... ["google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("www.google.com")
... ["www.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("ftp://ftp.google.com")
... ["ftp.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("http://www.google.com")
... ["www.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("http://www.google.com/")
... ["www.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("https://www.google.com/")
... ["www.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("https://www.google.com.sg/")
... ["www.google.com.sg"]
```

Comment: Omgawd thanks! Love that regex, short n' sweet~
Although I'm still trying to figure out how it works lol...

Also, `>>> regex.exec("ftp://www.google.com")
... ["ftp.google.com"]`, how'd you get that? haha :)

Comment: just to add few bits, a domain name may also have a hyphen sign `-`, may you need to adjust the same.

Comment: @pushpraj and how would I add it to the regex? I'm not really that good at regex so yeah... lol

Comment: @Unihedron I still can't figure it out how u did it, care to explain how it works?

Comment: @Cheejyg What we would like to match is a `aaa.bbb(.ccc.ddd.eee...)` sequence. I did this by quoting the characters as `[\w-]+` (any Word Character or hyphens), having another group as the characters with a dot `(?:[\w-]+\.)`, and quantify it to allow matching more than one time. `+`.

Comment: @Unihedron Cool I understand now, thanks! Btw, is this, `/[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+/`, the same as your regex?

Comment: Yes. Try out the demo and replace the regex in the grid with yours - it's the same. Messing around regexes are also good ways of learning them. :)

Comment: @stumped221 what do you mean "only hit on"? do you want `\.(?:com|net)` *somewhere in* the sequence or *at the end of* the sequence?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex in Javascript:

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?([^\/\n]+)\/?
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bQ4eJ8/1)

Comment: As a note for users, the regex __captures__ the target String. See [this](http://regex101.com/r/bQ4eJ8/2).

Comment: This regex doesn't really work because hardcoding `http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc. makes it very tedious and complicated to add new schemes. e.g. `"file://www.example.com/"` == `\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?([^\/\n]+)\/?` and so on..