# Regex to capture domain name from string including email addresses for specific tld's

Tags: javascript, regex, url, subdomain

I need regex that can parse domain names from strings including the domain from email addresses.  I found the following regex on StackOverflow:

```
/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/
```

Which works famously according to the demo provided:  https://regex101.com/r/aF1cY0/5

I got the regex from a different question on StackOverflow here:

[How to get domain from a string using javascript regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323126/how-to-get-domain-from-a-string-using-javascript-regular-expression)

I'd like to change the existing regex to only match specific TLD's (e.g.. com|net|biz)

Since I'm a total newb to regex I'm having trouble figuring out where to put that stipulation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `\b(?:[\w-]+\.)+(?:com|net|biz)\b` -> https://regex101.com/r/aQu3t1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(?:[\w-]+\.)+(?:com|net|biz)/i`

```js
function check(){
  var str = prompt("URL example: ");
  var match = str.match(/(?:[\w-]+\.)+(?:com|net|biz)/i);
  if(match)
    alert("Your domain is: '" + match + "'");
  else
    alert("Sorry! Nothing matched!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">TRY</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?:[\w-]+\.)+com|net|biz
```

Comment: this will match `"biz"` and `"net"`. You should group `com|net|biz` inside a non-capturing group like `(?:com|net|biz)`.